# Problem serving html form file using middleware

Tags: middleware

Often times, I have issue locating files from root directory. I have made this simple register form, I serve html form files to user.js then serve the user.js to the main server.js using middleware function. i.e app.use(). I was hoping to see the link from the index.html display and finally post the form to be sure that I got the absolute path but to no avail. i have been struggling two days for this please help.
project link: [https://glitch.com/~testnodemailer-message](https://glitch.com/%7Etestnodemailer-message)

Comment: Can you clarify what the routing flow *should* be, along with what you're seeing happen instead?

Comment: Jenn thanks for your attention, i was able to solve the pro